# Adding a namespace to a nested element

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have some XML similar to this:

```
<envelope xmlns="http://test">
  <header>
    <msgId />
  </header>
  <body>
    <element1 />
  </body>
</envelope>
```

I want to add a namespace to the `<element1>` node. Can anyone help me how to do this with XSLT?

Comment: Hi ,

I have  a xml similar to this 

<envelope xmlns="http:\\test">
  <header>
       <msgId/>
  </header>
  <body>
       <element1>
  </body>

I want to add a namespace to node <element1> . can anyone help me how to do this with xslt
 <element1 xmlns="http:\\test2">

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="element1">
    <xsl:element name="element1" namespace="http:..."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Attribute Value Templates with `name()`

```
<xsl:template match="element1">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://other-namespace">
  …
```

with identity transformation will give you

```
<envelope xmlns="http:\\test">
  <header>
    <msgId/>
  </header>
  <body>
    <element1 xmlns="http://other-namespace"/>
    …
```